# Avoid using CSS :before and :after

Tags: css, css-position, pseudo-element

I need to hide a `<label>` when on a small mobile view.

Here's the html:

```
<label class="page_createpassword_label" for="page_createpassword">
<span class="page_label_main">Span Text</span>
<span class="page-hide">. </span>
<span class="page-label-hint">
<strong>Information text</strong>
<span class="page-hide">. </span>
<span>More Span text</span>
</span>
</label>
```

The label is currently hidden using `:before` and `:after` selectors but as I'm trying to make it work for Android 2.3 so I can't use these.

The current CSS to hide the `<label>` is as follows:

```
.page-label-hint:before,
.page-rtl .page-label-hint:after {
    display: none;
}
```

And

```
.page-label-hint:before {
left: -21px;
}
```

Is there any way to hide the label using another method and avoiding the `:before` and `:after` selectors?  I was perhaps thinking along the lines of `display: none`.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show some HTML? What is confusing is that the `:before` and `:after` selectors add text to the elements and are not strictly for adjusting layouts.  Is there actually a `<label>` element in the document?

Comment: Why can't you just hide the label itself?

Comment: @MarcAudet I've added some HTML code to my question.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @winseybash With the code you have included, there is no difference between adding or removing the mentioned css.  Can you perhaps reproduce the issue in a stack snippet or jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @JamesMontagne I know it doesn't appear to change but when viewed on a mobile device with Android 2.3 or below it does.  The text appears on the screen when it's meant to be hidden.

Comment: @winseybash Please see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pspbc4go/  Nothing is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media all and (max-width: 450px) {

    .page_createpassword_label {

       display:none; 
    }

}
```

You can now hide the label in the mobile view. ;) Might need to adjust the media query to suit your needs. You can read about media queries here: http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Enjoy